# Python/Numpy: get top k largest values in a 2D matrix as a mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a 3x3 matrix like this:

```
array([[8, 6, 3],
       [6, 7, 2],
       [0, 8, 9]])
```

Now I want to get the top k largest values in the matrix, and create a mask from it. If the number is in the top k largest, it has value 1, else 0. Let `k=2`. In the example above there are one `9` and two `8`, we need to take all of them, so the returned mask is like this:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386432/how-to-get-indexes-of-k-maximum-values-from-a-numpy-multidimensional-array) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103908/finding-indices-of-k-top-values-in-a-2d-array-matrix) answer, and I can use the indices as the mask. However, I wonder if there is any better solution?

Comment: Better in what terms? Performance, readability, length of code?

Comment: `np.argpartition` is a great solution and I doubt you can find something much faster or much shorter (at least not without more provided information).

Comment: the problem with argpartition is how to handle duplicate values. See my own [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67253650/758174) on the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```py
def is_topk(a, k=1):
    _, rix = np.unique(-a, return_inverse=True)
    return np.where(rix < k, 1, 0).reshape(a.shape)
```

Example on your array:

```py
>>> is_topk(a, 1)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])

>>> is_topk(a, 2)
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
```